# Bootstrap multiple data api per element

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have an accordion that expands on click but I would also like a popover on hover.

Initially, I had the following code which called two "data-toggle" on one element.  This broke the popover.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"  >
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#parent-id" href="#collapse-id" data-container="body"  data-placement="top" data-content="data to be shown on popover" class="popoverClass"> 
          CLICK
        </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

**.js**

```
$('.popoverClass').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
```

Next I tried to name parent div as the popover element but this broke both the accordion and the popover

```
<div class="panel panel-default popoverClass" data-container="body"  data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="data to be shown on popover">
  <div class="panel-heading"  >
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#parent-id" href="#collapse-id"> 
          CLICK
        </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems like there is a bug with Bootstrap that is being fixed https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7011, a few responses suggested using SPAN or DIV as separate elements to id the popover but I can't seem to get it to function properly.

Here is a JFiddle with a functioning accordion

http://jsfiddle.net/L38U8/

Here is a JFiddle with functioning popover

http://jsfiddle.net/37KQt/

Here is JFiddle with working popover with accordion

http://jsfiddle.net/csaVg/

Can anyone see errors in my code?

Any suggestions?

Comment: will get a better response by providing a demo in jsfiddle.net or http://plnkr.co that others can see the issue and fork possible solutions

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I tried to duplicate the error in JFiddle but am not sure if it is my lack of JFiddle experience or my actual code.  How can I add bootstrap JS to JFiddle?

Comment: get url's for bootstrap cdn resources ( js and css) and add them to External Resources dropdown in jsfiddle. EVen easier at plnkr, just click to add them from "packages" on the right

Comment: I have added JFiddles but could not reproduce the error...yet cannot reproduce success in code base.

Comment: @MicFin [This](http://jsfiddle.net/csaVg/1) seems to work fine.

Comment: The official docs endorse the wrapper element solution: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/a6214273b9f9a7d4858e55ac2c5379f71ab71314/docs/_includes/js/overview.html#L14

Comment: @icanhazkittenz yes the jfiddle works fine but for some reason my code does not...are there any common reasons that JS would not trigger? I am #newb

Comment: failing in all browsers? any errors thrown in developer tools console? any html being dynamically loaded by ajax?

Comment: @charlietfl I ended up using a tooltip and attached it to the H4 element and that worked fine.